# DataTable internals and multithreaded usage

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, datatable

I would like to know if there is great book or website that discusses in great detail how to use DataTable in a multithreaded way.  It should discusses in great detail how it behave upon add, get, update and deletion of rows.  It should also discuss the proper way of using locks, acceptchanges and other important details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DataTables aren't special: just reading from a `DataTable` instance is thread-safe (as it says in the documentation), but if you *change* any aspect of an instance you have to make sure that you synchronize access to it.

Instead of looking for something specific to multithreading data tables, you should read about threading in general. For that, you can't go wrong with Joseph Albahari's [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

(Having said that, take a look at [this discussion thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/11b69e1a-ad6c-48d5-8e14-264af5b0692e) on a related topic.)

Answer (score 4):

I do not think you are going to find a whole of lot of information on the topic. That is a pretty narrow topic for a book and `DataTable`s are not really know for being all that useful in parallelized algorithms. The problem with `DataTable`s is that `DataRow`s are married to them in obscure ways. For example, changing a column value in a `DataRow` that is part of a primary key will update the parent `DataTable`'s index. This makes it a lot harder to get meaningful parallel throughput because you pretty much have to lock access to *everything* when making any kind of changes. However, `DataTable`'s and `DataRow`s are safe for multiple readers (as long as there are no writers) so all is not lost.